# Calculate age as of end of pay period

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have been tasked to calculate age based on date of birth as of end of every two weeks (pay period). Is that possible?

I can calculate as of sysdate but cant think of how I can achieve this task.

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyy')-TO_CHAR(PAE.BIRTHDATE,'yyyy') > 50
```

| Hire Date | Birth Date | Term Date | Employee Status | BSI Group | Age Years | Months | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04/05/2021 | 12/20/1971 | 01/01/1700 | A1 | 50 | 49 | 3 | 13 |

Comment: To restate the problem:  in a given two week time frame block, how old is someone based on their birthday?

Comment: What is the end of every two weeks?  I'm guessing Friday but that may be different in different countries.  Assuming the end of the week is Friday, is April 2, 2021 the end of a two week period?  Or is April 9, 2021?

Comment: @Makoto - yes.  I want the age based on the end of pay period - Monday to Sunday. So if someone is running the report on a Wednesday, it should calculate the age based on the end of that pay period.

Comment: @Justin Cave payroll is biweekly - Monday to Sunday.

Comment: OK.  Is April 4, 2021 the end of a pay period?  Or is April 11, 2021?

Comment: @JustinCave - April 4th is the end of the pay period. We start processing payroll April 5th with pay date April 11th.

Comment: OK.  So if someone runs the report on April 1, you want their age as of April 4?  And if someone runs the report on April 5, you want their age as of April 18?  Is that right?  Does the date you start processing payroll or the pay date have any bearing on the calculation?

Comment: @JustinCave that is a correct. If someone is running the report Apr 5th, they want to see the age as of April 18th. No. The pay dates are set in stone.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at your example

> TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyy')-TO_CHAR(PAE.BIRTHDATE,'yyyy') > 50

it seems that you just want to know whether a person is over 50 years old
(there may be more age brackets).

You could use the ADD_MONTHS() function for just adding 600 months to the
individual DOB values, and then check whether this "calculated date" is after the payment date.  The following queries are just a rough illustration.

**Test data: person & DOB**

```
-- person 100 will be 50 years old on 16 April 2021 -> must be in the "over 50" bracket thereafter
create table persondetails( id primary key, dob )
as
select 1, date '1955-01-01' from dual union all
select 2, date '1965-01-01' from dual union all
select 100, date '1971-04-16' from dual union all
select 3, date '1975-01-01' from dual union all
select 4, date '1985-01-01' from dual union all
select 5, date '1995-01-01' from dual union all
select 6, date '2005-01-01' from dual 
;


-- sysdate ie today's date is: 2021-04-03
select id
, case 
    when add_months( dob, 600 ) > sysdate then 'under 50'
    else 'over 50'
  end age_bracket
from persondetails 
;

ID  AGE_BRACKET
1   over 50
2   over 50
100 under 50
3   under 50
4   under 50
5   under 50
6   under 50
```

**Test data: paydates and payroll (every person gets paid on every "paydate")**

```
-- payments every fortnight
create table paydates
as
select date '2021-02-12' + ( level * 14 ) paydate
from dual
connect by level <= 12 ;


create table payroll
as 
select P1.id, P2.paydate
from (
  select id from persondetails
) P1 
cross join (
  select paydate from paydates
) P2
;
```

**View**

```
create or replace view paa -- payment dates and age
as
select P1.id
, P1.dob
, P2.paydate
, case 
    when add_months( P1.dob, 600 ) > P2.paydate then 'under 50'
    else 'over 50'
  end age_bracket
from persondetails P1 join payroll P2 on P1.id = P2.id 
;
```

**Final query & result**

```
select * from paa where id = 100 order by paydate ;

ID  DOB          PAYDATE    AGE_BRACKET
100 16-APR-71   26-FEB-21   under 50
100 16-APR-71   12-MAR-21   under 50
100 16-APR-71   26-MAR-21   under 50
100 16-APR-71   09-APR-21   under 50
100 16-APR-71   23-APR-21   over 50
100 16-APR-71   07-MAY-21   over 50
100 16-APR-71   21-MAY-21   over 50
100 16-APR-71   04-JUN-21   over 50
100 16-APR-71   18-JUN-21   over 50
100 16-APR-71   02-JUL-21   over 50
100 16-APR-71   16-JUL-21   over 50
100 16-APR-71   30-JUL-21   over 50
```

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=406eb1314a0a68c8673cb8c469ebcee5)

**ADDENDUM**

In an [Oracle Community discussion](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2133954/how-to-get-date-difference-in-terms-of-years-months-and-days), user Blue Shadow has posted a solution for the "Years Months Days" problem (under "Accepted Answer"):

```
>   select c_start_date, c_end_date
>          ,trunc(months_between(c_end_date, c_start_date) / 12) as yrs
>          ,trunc(mod(months_between(c_end_date, c_start_date), 12)) as mnths
>          ,trunc(c_end_date - add_months(c_start_date, trunc(months_between(c_end_date, c_start_date)))) as dys   from t
```

You can add this to the "view code", and get the years/months/days values.  Example see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4789f5ea1eefd3288f24373a3068ed27).

```
-- eg results for id 100
ID  DOB         PAYDATE     AGE_BRACKET YRS MNTHS DYS
100 16-APR-71   26-FEB-21   under 50    49  10  10
100 16-APR-71   12-MAR-21   under 50    49  10  24
100 16-APR-71   26-MAR-21   under 50    49  11  10
100 16-APR-71   09-APR-21   under 50    49  11  24
100 16-APR-71   23-APR-21   over 50     50  0   7
100 16-APR-71   07-MAY-21   over 50     50  0   21
100 16-APR-71   21-MAY-21   over 50     50  1   5
100 16-APR-71   04-JUN-21   over 50     50  1   19
```